# If Else use in sqlite database update queery

Tags: python, sqlite

I have problem in my table cloum name status have two possible condition status 'open' and status 'closed'.
I want update when status is open and if closed then rollback.

```
con6=sqlite3.connect("inv_clossing_datail_1.db")
cur6=con6.cursor()
cur6.execute(''' SELECT * FROM inv_closing_db WHERE Invoice_no = {}         '''.format(int(inv_sta2_e2.get())))
#cur6.execute(''' SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inv_closing_db WHERE Invoice_no = {} '''.format(int(inv_sta2_e2.get())))
search_inv_sta = cur6.fetchall()

if ('Status == "Closed" ')  in search_inv_sta:
    print("Alredy Closed This Invoice")
else:
    print("This Invoice is OPEN NOT CLOSED")
```

How this possible with best and easy way.

Comment: Don't use string formatting to substitute variables in SQL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is just nonsense.  If the question you want to ask is "what is the status of this invoice?" then you need:

```
cur6.execute('SELECT Status FROM inv_closing_db WHERE Invoice_no = ?', (int(inv_sta2_e2.get()),)
search_inv_sta = cur6.fetchall()[0]

if search_inv_sta[0] == "Closed":
    print("Alredy Closed This Invoice")
else:
    print("This Invoice is OPEN NOT CLOSED")
```

`fetchall` returns the record(s) as a list of lists, where each row is a list of fields.  Thus, we use [0] to pull the first record.  Then, `search_inv_sta[0]` grabs the first field from that row.

Answer (score 1):

> I want update when status is open and if closed then rollback.

It is unclear what you actually want especially in regard to "rollback".

- in SQLite typically a roll back is when undertaking a transaction, but that is an execution in it's own right and would be according to program logic as to whether a commit or rollback statement is executed; when perhaps there is only a need to update what needs to be updated.

You could be doing a mass update and thus any closed will result in nothing being done, so the column would appear to be redundant.

You could be updating a single row and really mean only switch from open to closed. In this case all that is required is for the update to include in the WHERE clause a check for the status

e.g. perhaps along the lines of:-

```
UPDATE inv_closing_db SET status = 'closed' WHERE status = 'open' /* other conditions if need be */;
```

Perhaps what you mean is that you want the status set to rollback if the status is closed in which case a CASE WHEN THEN END ELSE, or part thereof, expression could be used.

e.g. perhaps along the lines of (what the title appears to imply):-

```
UPDATE inv_closing_db SET status = CASE status WHEN 'open' THEN 'closed' WHEN 'closed' THEN 'rollback' ELSE status END;
```

*In both examples the column that is set need not be the status column and the value could be replaced with an expression (which could itself contain CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END expression(s)).*

Of course there are other permutations of the interpretation of your question in regards to ***I want update***. It could be another column rather than the status column that you want to update. However, much of what has been said could be adapted accordingly.

You probably want to consider clarifying your question.

Answer (score 0):

I Found Best Solution:
In this Case we use 'in' keyword for searching a particular element in list, tuple and dictionary in python and any SQL database like MySQL, SQLite table rows are in tuple.

```
cur6.execute(''' SELECT * FROM inv_closing_db WHERE Invoice_no = {} '''.format(int(inv_sta2_e2.get())))
                    
                    
                    search_inv_sta = cur6.fetchall()[0]
                    if ("Closed" in search_inv_sta):
                    
                                
                                print("Alredy Closed This Invoice")
                    
                    else:
                                print("This Invoice is OPEN NOT CLOSED")
```